# Ple package is not reflecting after installation

Tags: python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, google-colaboratory

Code

```
!pip install git+git://github.com/ntasfi/PyGame-Learning-Environment
```

Response

```
    Collecting git+git://github.com/ntasfi/PyGame-Learning-Environment
..........    Successfully built ple
```

Code

```
from PIL import Image    
from ple import PLE
from ple.games.flappybird import FlappyBird
```

Response

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**ModuleNotFoundError**                       Traceback (most recent call last)
 in ()
      1 from PIL import Image
      2 
----> **3 from ple import PLE**
      4 from ple.games.flappybird import FlappyBird
      5

**ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ple'**

---

NOTE: If your import is failing due to a missing package, you can
manually install dependencies using either !pip or !apt.

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Answer (score 1):

You also need to `!pip install pygame`.

Here's a full example:
https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1jSEvjaUcIQd2fRsDfF_WO5P2NlizNMBL